# while loop into another file

Tags: function, python-3.x, while-loop

thanks for checking this out. So I am having a few problems.

1. I can't seem to get the desired output into another file. I am trying to simulate a receipt in a sense to show the description of the item, quantity, item cost, etc.. It doesn't seem to work right and usually puts a negative in there. I know that it has to do with entering a negative number to stop but I am kind of confused on this.
2. I can't seem to format correctly either. I want to round everything to two decimal places which I know is {:.2f} but, since I am trying to line these up in columns I can't seem to figure this out.

My Code:

```
def cashRegister():
    subTotal = 0
    total = 0
    salesTax = .085
    registerTableHeader = "{0:<15}{1:>35}{2:>10} {3:>10}{4:>10}\n"\
                           .format('Description', 'Qty', 'Unit Cost',\
                             'Item Cost', 'Subtotal')
    cashRegisterFile.write(str(registerTableHeader))


    quantityOfItem = int(input("Enter quantity of item: "))
    while(quantityOfItem > 0):
        itemDescription = str(input("Enter Item's description: ")[:30])
        itemCost = float(input("Enter item's cost: "))        
        subTotal = quantityOfItem * itemCost 
        total += subTotal
        quantityOfItem = int(input("Enter quantity of item: "))

    registerTable = "{0:<15}{1:>35}{2:>10} {3:>10} {4:>10}\n\n"\
            .format(itemDescription, quantityOfItem, itemCost, itemCost * \
                quantityOfItem, subTotal)      
    cashRegisterFile.write(str(registerTable))
```

Desired Output:

```
Description                     Qty Unit Cost Item Cost  Subtotal
First Item's Description          1     24.99     24.99     24.99
This is the second item's desc    5      2.00     10.00     34.99
This is the third item's descr   10     11.00    110.00    144.99

Sales Tax                                                   13.05
Total                                                      158.04
```

Thanks for looking at my post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to indent your writing of your items so that it will be executed fo each item in the `while` loop. You wrote only the item after the loop. Hence your negative number from th condition `while(quantityOfItem > 0):` had ben written to file.

I change the top of the loop to:

```
    while True:
        quantityOfItem = int(input("Enter quantity of item: "))
        if quantityOfItem <= 0:
            break
```

Format your numbers like `{4:>10.2f}` for two decimals:

```
def cashRegister(cashRegisterFile):
    subTotal = 0
    total = 0
    salesTax = .085
    registerTableHeader = ("{0:<30} {1:>10}{2:>10} {3:>10} {4:>10}\n".format(
            'Description', 'Qty', 'Unit Cost','Item Cost', 'Subtotal'))
    cashRegisterFile.write(registerTableHeader)

    while True:
        quantityOfItem = int(input("Enter quantity of item: "))
        if quantityOfItem <= 0:
            break
        itemDescription = input("Enter Item's description: ")[:30]
        itemCost = float(input("Enter item's cost: "))        
        subTotal = quantityOfItem * itemCost 
        total += subTotal

        registerTable = ("{0:<30} {1:>10}{2:>10.2f} {3:>10.2f} {4:>10.2f}\n".format(
                itemDescription, quantityOfItem, itemCost, itemCost * quantityOfItem,
                subTotal))   
        cashRegisterFile.write(registerTable)

with open('cash.txt', 'w') as cashRegisterFile:
    cashRegister(cashRegisterFile)
```

Content of `cash.txt`:

```
Description                           Qty Unit Cost  Item Cost   Subtotal
A long description of my produ          3      4.00      12.00      12.00
a                                       2      4.00       8.00       8.00
```

Comment: Thanks for helping! The only problem I have is that when I set the columns it won't stay. I have it set where it will only show the first 30 characters of the description but it will still move the rest of the string down the line. I can't quite figure that one out.

Comment: Changed the formatting strings. Should work now. See my updated answer.

Comment: Great that it helped. BTW, you can [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) an answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get back to you, I just did it! Thanks again for helping me.